# How to force MySQL to take 0 as a valid auto-increment value

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Long story short, I have a SQL file that I want to import as a `skel` style file, so this will be done repeatedly, programmatically. I can edit the SQL file however I want, but I'd rather not touch the application itself.

This application uses `userid = 0` to represent the anonymous user. It also has a relevant (blank) entry in the database to represent this 'user'. Hence, the line in my `skel.sql` looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `{{TABLE_PREFIX}}users` VALUES (0, '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '', '', '', NULL);
```

The problem with this is that `uid` is a `auto_increment` field, for which, technically, `0` is an invalid value. Or atleast, if you set it to 0, you're basically telling MySQL, "Please insert the next id into this field."

Now, I suppose I could put an `INSERT` then an `UPDATE` query into my SQL file, but is there a way of telling MySQL in general that yes, I actually want to insert `0` into this field?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

*From the answer I got [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/42071/how-to-force-mysql-to-take-0-as-a-valid-auto-increment-value/42074#42074):*

You can use:

```
SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'
```

Which as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero), will prevent MySQL from interpreting an INSERT/UPDATE ID of 0 as being the next sequence ID. Such behaviour will be limited to NULL.

It is what I'd consider pretty bad behaviour from the application though. You'll have to be real careful that it's used consistently, especially if you choose to implement replication at a later date.

Comment: One thing you have to be careful about: `sql_mode` is a comma-delimited list of flags. If you do `sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'`, you may be inadvertently disabling other flags

Comment: This solution basically worked for me, however my dump also included some places where it was overriding the `sql_mode` in the middle of the sql file and then resetting to the variable `OLD_SQL_MODE` which was set to revert back to at the end of the script. This was overriding my `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` in the middle of my script making this not work. My solution was to create a new variable of `INIT_OLD_SQL_MODE` I used to reset to at the end and after I set `sql_mode` to `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`, I set a new variable of `OLD_SQL_MODE` that those temporary overrides could reset to

Answer (score 32):

Check your sql DB mode with:

```
SELECT @@[GLOBAL|SESSION].sql_mode;
```

If it's empty or not set, use:

```
SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'
```

BE CAREFUL! If you use **`GLOBAL`**, it's not an immediate change, you need to restart your connection to apply the setting.

So, if you're restoring data from one DB to another, for example, and you're not sure if this setting is applied, use **`SESSION`** for an immediate change (it resets when closing the connection). When done, insert 0 value and it won't change even if the `sql_mode` is changed.

To reset this mode (and others) use

```
SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] sql_mode=''
```

Zero auto-increment values are not recommended because they're not set as default in MySQL databases.

For more info check [mysql dev page topic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero) on this

**Update**

For MariaDB use the command pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142472/how-to-force-mysql-to-take-0-as-a-valid-auto-increment-value/3675806?noredirect=1#comment87031879_3675806)

```
SET sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'
```

Comment: Did not work: SELECT @@[GLOBAL|SESSION].sql_mode;
Did work: SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
Did work: SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;

Comment: @azoundria that's actually the way it's presented for optionally select GLOBAL or SESSION => `[GLOBAL|SESSION]`

Answer (score 19):

If you do not want to deal with mysql variables, here's a useful hack:

```
INSERT INTO `{{TABLE_PREFIX}}users` VALUES (-1, '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '', '', '', NULL);
```

And then

```
UPDATE `{{TABLE_PREFIX}}users` SET id = 0 where id = -1;
```

Obviously, this assumes that you're using a signed integer and not using negative values for your table ids.

Comment: Obviously, it does not work if you're using an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 11):

Fail safe way:

```
SET @@session.sql_mode = 
    CASE WHEN @@session.sql_mode NOT LIKE '%NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO%' 
        THEN CASE WHEN LENGTH(@@session.sql_mode)>0
            THEN CONCAT_WS(',',@@session.sql_mode,'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO')  -- added, wasn't empty
            ELSE 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'                                    -- replaced, was empty
        END
        ELSE @@session.sql_mode                                             -- unchanged, already had NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO set
    END
```

- Checks if NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO already set in sql_mode
- Adds to sql_mode if not empty
- Sets only the session, I recommend using it only on the sessions where you need to insert a 0