# Mysql - how to set auto-increment to start from zero

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I just want my mysql table id(primary key) to start from 0..

As I have seen, I used ALTER TABLE yourtable AUTO_INCREMENT =0 but it starts from 1..What is that I need to do?

Edit1

I also emptied my table with truncate option

Comment: Why? Don't try to influence the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. Leave it up to the database to do it. It's arbitrary anyway. If you want to add some kind of ID you want to assign yourself, you shouldn't make it `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Could be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142472/how-to-force-mysql-to-take-0-as-a-valid-auto-increment-value

Comment: @BartFriederichs actually it has to do some work with arrays in php so i need it..guess I will start from 1 and decrement it in my php code for arrays..

Comment: @BartFriederichs will it work ok when I try to access it?? I mean with index 0??

Comment: Check the answer posted by Mathew...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142472/how-to-force-mysql-to-take-0-as-a-valid-auto-increment-value

Comment: @user2234992 if you want to populate an array from db, then use associative arrays as they are more faster and occupies less memory. If you delete few rows from DB, then indexed array will still occupy memory even their value is not assigned

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'
```

> NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO affects handling of AUTO_INCREMENT columns. Normally, you generate the next sequence number for the column by inserting either NULL or 0 into it. NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO suppresses this behavior for 0 so that only NULL generates the next sequence number.
>
> This mode can be useful if 0 has been stored in a table's AUTO_INCREMENT column. (Storing 0 is not a recommended practice, by the way.)

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero)

[Reference 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/42071/how-to-force-mysql-to-take-0-as-a-valid-auto-increment-value/42074#42074)

Comment: wtf? Why isn't zero okay. It's a perfectly normal number.

Comment: @Fuser97381: yes it's a number but it makes life harder. In many programming languages, you have to pay attention when you use boolean functions and pass a 0 as argument. For example, in php,  some functions interpret  0 as FALSE. if you get an id from the database, store it in the variable $id and you use : empty($id), to check if $id is a valid id, that function returns FALSE when $id = 0.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot force this to be zero. This is limited by **auto_increment_offset** server variable. The default value is 1, the range is [1 .. 65535].

More information: [auto_increment_offset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset), [How to set AUTO_INCREMENT step](http://web.archive.org/web/20191020150603/http://buysql.com/mysql/54-how-to-set-autoincrement-step.html).

Comment: Hi Devart. Second link is dead (now the link redirects to advertisements)