# Get all ID's from one table and insert values in another table based on it

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have two tables:

Table 1: Companies (id, name)
Table 2: Holidays (id, companyId, name)

Currently companies table have data, but holidays doesn't. I want to iterate through all companies, get their ID's and insert two records in holidays for every company. So this would be before and after:

Before:

```
Companies
| id | name  |
|  0 | test1 |
|  1 | test2 |
```

Holidays:
`Empty table`

After:

```
Companies
| id | name  |
|  0 | test1 |
|  1 | test2 |
```

```
Holidays:
| id | companyId | name     | 
|  0 |         0 | holiday1 |
|  1 |         0 | holiday2 |
|  2 |         1 | holiday1 |
|  3 |         1 | holiday2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Holidays.id is set to auto increment:

```
insert into Holidays (select id as companyId, 'holiday1' as name from Companies);
insert into Holidays (select id as companyId, 'holiday2' as name from Companies);
```

Comment: You cannot force an auto incremented value to start from zero : [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16232681/5841306)

Comment: Yeah. I have trouble with this. How can I avoid that? it says column count doesnt match value count if I do not provide any value for auto increment, eventhough the id column is set as AI

Answer (score 1):

You need a self-join for `Companies` table and an iteration logic to produce `id` column values for `Holidays`. So consider using :

```
insert into Holidays(id,company_id,name)
select @rn := @rn + 1, c1.id, concat('Holiday',(c1.id+1))
  from Companies c1
  join Companies c2
  join (select @rn := -1) as q_iter;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fff9f32d6d507547d1b8a77ebb5385d8)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
insert into holidays (companyId, name)
    select c.companyId, h.name
    from companies c cross join
         (select 1 as ord, 'holiday1' as name union all
          select 2 as ord, 'holiday2'
         ) h
    order by c.companyId, h.ord;
```

This assumes that `holidays.id` is an auto-incremented column.  If not, you should make it one.  If not, though, you can use `row_number()`:

```
insert into holidays (id, companyId, name)
    select row_number() over (order by c.companyId, h.ord),
           c.companyId, h.name
    from companies c cross join
         (select 1 as ord, 'holiday1' as name union all
          select 2 as ord, 'holiday2'
         ) h
    order by c.companyId, h.ord;
```

Or a parameter:

```
insert into holidays (id, companyId, name)
    select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id,
           c.companyId, h.name
    from companies c cross join
         (select 1 as ord, 'holiday1' as name union all
          select 2 as ord, 'holiday2'
         ) h cross join
         (select @rn := 0) params
    order by c.companyId, h.ord;
```